# SQLAlchemy with server side cursors and need to close the result set early - but the program hangs till the resultset is exhausted?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mariadb

I'm trying to use the following coding style with SQLAlchemy to process millions of rows of data, and have a need to abort the result fetch part way through. How can I close a result set and force the underlying connection to stop sending unwanted data and halt the query?

In other words when #close() is called on the result set, why does the underlying code continue to stream data to effectively /dev/null? How can I stop it from streaming data?

Using SQLAlchemy 2.0.3 on Linux.

```py
with self._engine.execution_options(stream_results=True).connect() as conn:
    result: Result
    with conn.execute(stmt) as result:
        print("pre-consumer")
        consumer(result)
        print("post-consumer")
        # Code hangs here while MariaDB is continuing to send data.
        result.close()
```

I'm using the following connection URL:

`mariadb+mariadbconnector://_user_:***@mariadb.localnet/db?allowMultiQueries=true&charset=utf8mb4&dumpQueriesOnException=true&includeInnodbStatusInDeadlockExceptions=true&tcpAbortiveClose=false&useCompression=true`

Example consumer:

```
def _print_10_ids(result: Result) -> None:
    ix: int = 0
    for article_id in result.scalars():
        print(f"{ix}: {article_id:,}")
        ix += 1
        if ix >= 10:
            # Stop processing rows and return.
            return
```

Comment: so the consumption of data takes times, so you need to optimize it, butthis has nothing to do with sql

Comment: My need is to stop the server side cursor from continuing to send data after the code detects a condition which indicates additional rows of data are not needed.

Comment: you can't you send a command and the sever runs till it finsihes, if you have a slow select, use limit offset , ti grap portions at a time, still i don't know what vonsumes means, as is said, when you reach your function the query is already finished.

Comment: The result set is being streamed and the code starts processing the result set immediately while the server is still sending data. I want to close the connection without blowing up the entire connection pool when needing to early terminate the stream by closing it.

Comment: we still don't know how consumer looks like, but if you want to process it row by row you need to change your code see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html

Comment: Consumer example added. Explicit #close() added (which is implicit at context block end)

Comment: While the native MariaDB Connector/C supports server side cursors (read only forward cursors), SQLAlchemy doesn't. So I wonder about the title "SQLAlchemy with server side cursors". Likely you mean unbuffered result sets, but not server side cursors.

Comment: The documentation at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mysql.html#server-side-cursors indicates that server side cursors are supported. Also https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#engine-stream-results provides more generalized info.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL python connection library "pymysql" will exhaust the cursor when close is called, effectively forcing the server to transfer the remaining result set only for it to be immediately discarded.

The MariaDb python connection library has the following which implies it should be able to stop result fetching and end the transaction, but it doesn't seem to do this in practice:

```py
class cursor(object):
    """ Returns a MariaDB cursor object """
    def close(self): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        """
        Closes the cursor. If the cursor has pending or unread results, .close()
        will cancel them so that further operations using the same connection
        can be executed.
        
        The cursor will be unusable from this point forward; an Error (or subclass)
        exception will be raised if any operation is attempted with the cursor.
        """
        pass
```

Therefore stopping the result fetch isn't possible connecting to MySQL or MariaDB with either library it seems. Defective by design?

Also see comments here: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/9356